# Comparing two lists containing dates in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two functions `dte()` and generate `dates()`, both of them print dates in a specific range.

```
def dte(): 
    date = (' '.join(map(str,ddt)))      
    return date

print dte()


def generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
    td = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        print current_date
        current_date += td
    start_date = datetime.date(2017, 10, 25)
    end_date = datetime.date(2017, 10, 28)
```

`dte()` contains some missing dates ,while `generate_dates()` is complete. How do I compare them and store in  another list with missing values as 0 ?

For example: `[2017-10-25 , 0 , 2017-10-27 , 0 , 0 , 2017-10-30...]`

Edit: Here is the output when I print both the functions:

```
('2017-07-26',) ('2017-07-27',) ('2017-07-28',) ('2017-07-29',)       ('2017-07-30',) ('2017-07-31',) ('2017-08-01',) ('2017-08-02',) ('2017-08-03',) ('2017-08-04',) ('2017-08-05',) ('2017-08-08',) ('2017-08-09',) ('2017-08-10',) ('2017-08-11',) ('2017-08-12',) ('2017-08-14',) ('2017-08-16',) ('2017-08-17',) ('2017-08-18',) ('2017-08-19',) ('2017-08-21',) ('2017-08-22',) ('2017-08-23',) ('2017-08-24',)

2017-07-26
2017-07-27
2017-07-28
2017-07-29
2017-07-30
2017-07-31
2017-08-01
2017-08-02
2017-08-03
2017-08-04
2017-08-05
2017-08-06
2017-08-07
2017-08-08
2017-08-09
2017-08-10
2017-08-11
2017-08-12
2017-08-13
2017-08-14
2017-08-15
2017-08-16
2017-08-17
2017-08-18
2017-08-19
2017-08-20
2017-08-21
2017-08-22
2017-08-23
2017-08-24
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please give us some data. Ideally, representative input and output required. Please also read: [mcve].

Comment: Output added in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using your own code:

```
import datetime

ddt = [
    datetime.date(2017,10,25),
    datetime.date(2017,10,27),
    datetime.date(2017,10,28),
]

def generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
    res = []
    td = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        res.append(current_date)
        current_date += td
    return res

start_date = datetime.date(2017, 10, 25)
end_date = datetime.date(2017, 10, 30)

all_dates = generate_dates(start_date, end_date)

res = []
for date in all_dates:
    if date not in ddt:
        res.append(0)
    else:
        res.append(date)

print map(str, res)
```

Output:

```
['2017-10-25', '0', '2017-10-27', '2017-10-28', '0', '0']
```

Note that I changed `generate_dates()` function to return the complete range of dates (not to just print them).

Also note that this code is not optimal. It will have complexity of O(N*M), where N - is size of `ddt`, and M - size of `all_dates`. So it's definitely not optimal for large lists. If your list `ddt` is big, you might want to convert it to a set, before the final cycle:

```
ddt = set(ddt)
```

This way the complexity will be O(M).

Comment: I tried this method ,however it doesn't work when the month is less than 10,Eg. Since dates from database are returned as ['2017-07-26', '2017-07-27'] and dates from datetime function are returned as [datetime.date(2017, 7, 26), datetime.date(2017, 7, 27), datetime.date(2017, 7, 28), datetime.date(2017, 7, 29), the output returned is ['0','0','0'..]

Comment: @Justinj64, you need to convert dates contained in strings to `date` objects. You can do this by: `ddt = map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date(), ddt)`